# How to combine font weights and font sizes together?

Tags: typography, font-weight

I do a lot of UI design and because of this, I normally have to use pretty neutral fonts like Helvetica and Droid.  In order to add a bit of flair, I'll use different weights and mix things up between ALL CAPS and normal case.

Sometimes I find myself guessing if it's best to use a thicker weight vs. caps.  Does anybody have any tips or general guidelines when it's best to use one or the other?

I remember reading before that the bigger the font, the thinner it should be so there's a common thickness between different sizes within your font scale.  But then does that not make everything look too generic as not enough contrast is given?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://practicaltypography.com/

Comment: Typographic treatment is all relative to your subject matter. There are two schools of thought. 

One school is: type is to be read. The more contrast in your type, the less readable everything becomes. This discipline would encourage your argument, thin larger fonts.

The other school is: type is an extension of your design. If your design is catering to an audience that favors contrast, then allow your type to be drastic. Type can be used as "entertainment." 

I prefer to match weights and let other elements be designerly (photos, charts, etc). Type should not have to work so hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My problem is that I deal so much with type that it becomes so central to my designs.  I think trying to make data more visual always helps

Comment: Just a comment about all caps vs. standard case: all caps is harder to read, as there's no differentiation in height, so it should be used sparingly.

(Also, Material design reserves all caps for buttons. Always take a look at platform typography guidelines when designing.)